# Taking absolute value of complex variable

Tags: complex

I'm trying to take absolute value squared of certain objects. Say I have

```
y=alpha
```

and I know that |alpha|^2 = alpha*Conjugate[alpha].

How do I take Abs[y]^2 without assigning a numerical value to alpha in mathematica?

Comment: Depending on the form of the output desired: `Clear[alpha]; Abs[alpha]^2 // ComplexExpand[#, {alpha}] &` or

`Abs[alpha]^2 // 
 ComplexExpand[#, {alpha}, TargetFunctions -> Conjugate] &`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
α = αr + I*αi;
Abs[α]^2 // ComplexExpand
```

> αi^2 + αr^2

Answer (score 1):

```
y[alpha_] := Abs[alpha]^2

ComplexExpand[y[a - I*b]]

a^2 + b^2
```